# Gradient of a norm function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

I know that the gradient of the least squares L2 norms is $\nabla\left \| Y-X\beta \right \|^2_2=2X^t(Y-X\beta)$

I have another similar function for which I calculated the gradient but I'm not sure if it is correct!
$\nabla\left \| Y-X(e^\beta+1)\right \|^2_2=2X^t(Y-X(e^\beta+1))e^\beta$
Is the $e^\beta$ at the end correct?

Comment: Your first gradient has the wrong sign:  $$\nabla\|y-X\beta\|^2_2=2X^T(X\beta-y)$$Your second gradient is wrong. The exponential function is applied element-wise, so the gradient is going to contain elementwise/Hadamard products.

Comment: @greg if I would use the same what you wrote for the second, wouldn't it be like this:
$\nabla\left \| y-X(e^\beta+1)\right \|^2_2=2X^T(X(e^\beta+1)-y)e^\beta$

Comment: Suppose $X=I,$ the identity matrix. Then the only thing left are the vectors. How will you handle the vector-vector product? The gradient is a vector, but how will you obtain a vector result from $ye^\beta = ?? $